# how to configure Protractor and Selenium Server?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, configuration, protractor

I have install JDK,Protractor and webdriver-manage by following this :

[Protractor install tutorial](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial)

but when i run this: webdriver-manager start
gets in my cmd 
seleniumProcess.

> pid: 4648 Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile
>   C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
>   rotractor\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar Selenium
>   Standalone has exited with code 1

how can i configure this??

Comment: @ alecxe can you guide me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove previous instance (.jar file) of web driver from the location- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p rotractor\selenium
2. Download the selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0 from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
   and replace the .jar file.

Comment: i am getting this now after doing that as you said 
C:\Users\HP>webdriver-manager start
Selenium Standalone is not present. Install with webdriver-manager update --stan

Comment: Could be a problem with the latest jar. Can you take the 2.44 version and try?