# Selenium webdriver exits with error code 135

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, runtime-error

I am new to protractor. I am getting the following error while trying to run Selenium tests using protractor

```
I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
E/launcher - Error code: 135
E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
at ClientRequest.<anonymous>  (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:381:15)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:267:9)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1269:8)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at Function.createSession  (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:329:24)
at Builder.build (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:458:24)
at Hosted.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:37:33)
at Runner.createBrowser (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:187:43)
at c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:261:30
at _fulfilled (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
at runSingle (c:\Users\SavDevService.SAVISIONLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

I checked to see if any other process is listening to port 4444, but did not find any. also I am running web driver with --standalone  flag.

Comment: Can you post your config file?  and what version of node and protractor?

Comment: either you are not running web driver or its get disconnected. Make sure that  selenium server running on mentioned port id - command: "**webdriver-manager start**"

Comment: Hi Farhana, I have run the windows command prompt as administrator and solved this problem.

Answer (score 18):

It seems like selenium server is not running on `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub`. Before running your protractor test,you must start the selenium server using below command.`webdriver-manager start`. After starting the server your tests will execute without any errors.

If you dont want to start selenium server manually,then just remove `seleniumAddress:http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` property from your conf.js.

Comment: What surprises me is that when I launch `webdriver-manager start` in Jenkins, I get a success message (`Selenium Server is up and running`) then the process freezes forever. Ever heard about this?

Comment: You need to use `nohup webdriver-manager start`. This is because you are starting selenium server which will not end until you stop the process. So to avoid this you need to start selenium server as a background process.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Jenkins Pipeline, I get the very same behaviour. I'll try to parallelize the tasks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add these lines to your `conf.js` file:

```
chromeOnly: true,
directConnect: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

Start the webdriver, its good to update the web driver and start the web driver before you start executing your automation test suite by executing the below commands in console screen.

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have selenium drivers installed for the browser you want to test with?
Try with

```
webdriver-manager update
```

It will take care of installing the drivers for you. You just need to run it once, if you call it again it will see that the drivers are already installed and will not procede.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start selenium server using this command `webdriver-manager start`?
If not there might be a problem with your configuration with selenium server.
I would suggest [follow this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645972/how-to-configure-protractor-and-selenium-server)

Solution 1

1. try `webdriver-manager update --standalone`

Solution 2

1. Remove previous instance (.jar file) of web driver from the location- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p rotractor\selenium
2. Download the selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0 from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and replace the .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

i also get this type of error, but after **set environment variables** this issue is solved. 
location of the npm;
Example:
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0):

The `directConnect` solution is nice when running `protractor` locally, but it didn't work when trying to do it on Jenkins. It seems like when running everything in Docker containers in Jenkins, you'll have to start `webdriver-manager start` in detached mode `-d` first, wait, and then start `protractor`.

Answer (score 0):

check your web driver status by the below command

```
 webdriver-manager status
```

if it's not up to date you can remove and install it by following these steps

```
 webdriver-manager clean
 webdriver-manager status
 webdriver-manager update
 webdriver-manager start
```

then start your web driver by

if you get this error

```
   ERROR [BaseServer.start] - Port 4444 is busy, please choose a free port and specify it using -port option
```

you can set another port by this command(for example port 4545)

```
 webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort 4545
```

then your selenium web driver will run

Answer (score -1):

I have run the windows command prompt as administrator and solved this problem. I am not seeing this problem anymore.
And I added also

```
chromeOnly: true,
directConnect: true,
```