# Getting an error with Protractor Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor, config, explorer

I keep running into issues with trying to get protractor working on my internet explorer code. I have chrome tests and it works for those but when i run it on IE i get an Error code of 135, and Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444. This is my config file below.

I've tried updating my npm stuff, adding a 'seleniumArgs' line of code, and

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
   // './IESpec.ts'
  ],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=your/path/to/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'],
  // capabilities: {
  //   'browserName': 'chrome',
  //   //'browserName': 'internet explorer',
  //   'sharedTestFiles': true,
  //   'maxInstances': 1,
  //   'chromeOptions': {
  //     'args': ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
  //     // 'args': ['incognito'],
  //     // 'args': [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu"]
  //   }
  capabilities: { 
    'browserName': 'internet explorer', 
    'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true, 
    'platform': 'ANY', 
    'version': '11', 
    args: ['--silent', '--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--lang=US', '--start-maximized'], //,'--headless', '--disable-gpu' 
    prefs: { 
        'download': {
            'prompt_for_download': false, 
            'directory_upgrade': true, 
            'extensions_to_open': '', 
            'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/downloads/'
        }, 
    } 
}, 
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: { 
    jvmArgs: [ 
        '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.14.0.exe'
    ] 
}, 
directConnect: false, 
framework: 'jasmine', 
seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.14.0.exe'], 
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  params: {
    login: {
      user: 'User',
      password: 'password'
    },
    url: {
      site: //'https://URL'
      'https://URL'
    }
  },
  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  beforeLaunch: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
  },
  onPrepare() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  },
  suites: {
    smoke: './e2e/smoke/*.ts',
  },
  afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
  }
};

This is the error message i get at the bottom

Report destination:   reports\Screenshots\report.html
[15:26:09] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:26:09] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[15:26:10] E/launcher - Error code: 135
[15:26:10] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
[15:26:10] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Comment: Are you certain that webdriver-manager is running? With `webdriver-manager start`.

Comment: Try to check and set environment variables may help to fix the issue. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353859/selenium-webdriver-exits-with-error-code-135

Comment: Yes. i'm certain. And also i've changed the securities in IE to not have the protected mode checkbox.

Comment: With no protected mode, Is it worked? Please let us know about the current status of the issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yep. I read that they need to be all on the same or all off. I got it working by adding
jvmArgs: ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.141.5.exe"] 
I'm not sure how this helped but it atleast started launching IE haha. My new issue is my chrome code works great but when i switch it to IE i get a 'UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement' error. I'm going to go do some research and possibly open another ticket.

Comment: From your last comment, It looks like your current issue is solved now. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. You can create a new thread for your new issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding jvmArgs: ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.141.5.exe"] I'm not sure how this helped but it atleast started launching IE